# Is Java EE Batch (JSR 352) going to be part of quarkus?

Tags: jsr352, quarkus

Batch API is pretty cool framework. JBoss implementation "jBeret" add even more some cool stuff like REST API and UI.

Is Batch API going to be part of Quarkus at some point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: we now have a Quarkus JBeret extension in the Quarkiverse: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jberet .