# quarkus supports batch implementation (JSR352)

Tags: batch-file, jsr352, quarkus

Is Quarkus supports batch implementation like (JSR352). I tried to search few examples and i couldnt find much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The same question is already posted. Its in the road map of Quarkus. Currently its not yet implemented.

[Is Java EE Batch (JSR 352) going to be part of quarkus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55297410/3933950)